# No rostopic response when run in docker container

Tags: docker, rostopic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run `rostopic hz <topic-name>` inside a docker container to get the publishing rate of a topic via the containers logs I don't get any output. (If I echo the same topic I get what I expect.) Do I miss something here?

```
In [1]: import docker
In [2]: cli = docker.from_env(version='auto')
In [3]: roscore = cli.containers.run(image='osrf/ros:indigo-desktop-trusty', network='host', command='
   ...: roscore', detach=True)
In [4]: publisher = cli.containers.run(image='osrf/ros:indigo-desktop-trusty', network='host', command
   ...: ='rostopic pub /topic_to_observe std_msgs/UInt8 42 -r 1', detach=True)
In [5]: rostopic = cli.containers.run(image='osrf/ros:indigo-desktop-trusty', network='host', command
    ...: ='rostopic hz /topic_to_observe', detach=True)
In [6]: rostopic.logs()
Out[6]: ''
In [7]: subscriber = cli.containers.run(image='osrf/ros:indigo-desktop-trusty', network='host', comman
   ...: d='rostopic echo /topic_to_observe', detach=True)
In [8]: subscriber.logs()
Out[8]: 'data: 42\n---\ndata: 42\n---\ndata: 42\n---\ndata: 42\n---\ndata: 42\n---\n'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290345/no-rostopic-response-when-run-in-docker-container/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-05-03

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-03**:
This looks like the output of an IPython console. Is this what you mean with "manually running"?

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-03**:
Right, I ran it in a IPython console which was no problem so far. If I run the command in my Ubuntu workstation environment I have the usual output:

```
❯ rostopic hz /topic_to_observe
subscribed to [/topic_to_observe]
average rate: 1.000
    min: 1.000s max: 1.000s std dev: 0.00000s windo
```

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-04**:
... I expected to get something similar with `In [6]: rostopic.logs() Out[6]: ''`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-04**:
I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but that is probably just me.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-04**:
Sorry, probably not clear enough: When I run `roscore`, a publisher node and `rostopic hz` I would expect the same output of `rostopic hz` when (a) I run them on Ubuntu directly or (b) I run them inside Docker containers (like done via the IPython console and `docker` Python package).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-04**:
Are they all running in the same container?

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-04**:
No, each is running in a separate container (via `<"docker-container-representation"> = cli.containers.run(...)` for all: `roscore`, `publisher`, `rostopic`, `subscriber`). But they share the same host network. (This was usually sufficient to enable cross-container ROS node communication.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah, I just noticed the `host` bit. That *should* work, so not sure. I've never really extensively used the Docker Python libs. Perhaps it's doing something strange with TTYs?

A quick google led me to [docker/docker-py/issues/390](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/390).

Notice the `tty=True` argument there.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-04**:
Thanks for that hint. It's not urgent right now. I'll have a look at this as soon as I can spend time on it and keep the question open for now.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-04**:
Thx. Changing to `rostopic = cli.containers.run(image='osrf/ros:indigo-desktop-trusty', network='host', command='rostopic hz /topic_to_observe', detach=True, tty=True)` solved this issue.